# Mostrar nombre de un registro usando el ID que se encuentra en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql

*Poseo dos tablas :*

**Personal: cédula, rango_id**

**Rangos: id_rango, rango(campo con la descripción del rango)**

Quisiera que al querer modificar el personal donde aparece seleccionado su rango
no aparecería su ID, como, 1 2 3 4, sino que aparecía la descripción que posee cada uno en la tabla.

Tengo el siguiente código, pero no se como mostrarlo. ¿ alguna idea para realizar esto?

```
   <script>
function confirmSav()
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Desea modificar este registro? ");
  if (agree)
  return true ;
else
   return false ;
}
</script>

<script>
function confirmDel()
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Desea eliminar este registro? ");
  if (agree)
  return true ;
else
   return false ;
}
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sino.js"></script>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "POST" action = "">
<h1 align ="center">Bienvenido</h1>
<a href ="index.html"><ol>Pagina Principal</ol></a>
<a href ="registrar.php"><ol>Registrar</ol></a>
<a href ="listado.php"><ol>Listado</ol></a>
<a href ="Sancion.php"><ol>Sancion</ol></a>
<h1>Listado<br></h1>
<?php
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
$contador = 0;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from personal");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros))
{
$contador=$contador+1;
echo $contador."<br>";
echo "NOMBRE: ".$reg['nombre']."<br>";
echo "APELLIDO: ".$reg['apellido']."<br>";
echo "CEDULA: ".$reg['cedula']."<br>";
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from personal");

$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT a.cedula, b.rango_id, b.rango
FROM   personal a 
LEFT JOIN rangos  b ON a.rango_id = b.id_rango
ORDER BY a.cedula ASC");
$reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros);

echo "RANGO: ".$reg['rango_id']."<br>";
echo "<a onClick='return confirmSav();' href=actualizar.php?cedula=".$reg['cedula']." >editar<a/>"."<br>";
echo "<a onClick='return confirmDel();' href=procesar3.php?cedula=".$reg['cedula']." >eliminar<a/>"."<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

> Nota , no se si deba agregar ademas esta linea al codigo:

```
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT a.cedula, b.rango_id, b.rango
FROM   personal a LEFT JOIN rangos  b ON a.rango_id = b.id_rango
ORDER BY a.cedula ASC");
$sql2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "RANGO: ".$sql2['rango']."<br>";
```

Comment: ahora?, ya lo modifique

Comment: Bien, solo te queda aceptarla

Comment: esperare los 2 días, por cierto podrías revisar mi otra pregunta :)

Comment: La leí pero no soy bueno ni con [tag:php] ni con [tag:mysql] v.v

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52013/discussion-between-victor-a-and-lois6b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas tomando `RANGO_ID` de la tabla de `RANGOS`, donde ese valor pertenece a `PERSONAL`, por lo que explicas al principio.
Sencillamente cambia este valor `b.rango_id` por `a.rango_id`de esta linea de codigo:

```
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT a.cedula, b.rango_id, b.rango

FROM   
    personal a 
LEFT JOIN 
    rangos  b ON a.rango_id = b.id_rango
ORDER BY 
    a.cedula ASC");

$reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros);
```

Funcionando:

```
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT a.cedula, a.rango_id, b.rango
FROM   
    personal a 
LEFT JOIN 
    rangos  b ON a.rango_id = b.id_rango
ORDER BY 
    a.cedula ASC");
$reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros);
```